# Count numeric chars in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using tsql I want to count a numeric chars in string. For example i've got 'kick0my234ass' string and i wanna count how many (4 in that example) numbers are in that string. I can't use regex, just plain tslq.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What have you tried?  Can you even find the first numeric?  Hint recursive cte.

Comment: Why can't you use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first have to split the character string in its individual characters, evaluate which are numeric, and finally count those that are. This will do the trick:

```
DECLARE @test  TABLE (Example NVARCHAR(255))

INSERT @test 
VALUES ('kick0my234ass')

SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    @test AS T
INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
        ON  v.type = 'P'
        AND v.number < len(T.Example)
WHERE   SUBSTRING(T.Example, v.number + 1, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You COULD do this I suppose:

```
declare @c varchar(30)

set @c = 'kick0my234ass'

select @c, len(replace(@c,' ','')) - len(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@c,'0',''),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''),' ',''))
```

Comment: Problem can happen if you have space or spaces before last number like 'kick0my234ass 5' . Second LEN would get trailing blanks, trim them and get you wrong answer.  You can add one more Replace to replace blanks with something.

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic I just tested and it works fine just the way it is for me, did it fail in the way you describe for you?

Comment: for 'kick0my234ass    5' will not return 5 but 9? 6 actually because SO here in comments deletes extra blanks

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic Sorry, you are right, I have implemented your solution, thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

using a Tally Table created by an rCTE:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (S varchar(100));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('kick0my234 ass');
GO
WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT 1 AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1
    FROM Tally
    WHERE N + 1 <= 100)
SELECT S.S, SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(S,T.N, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Numbers
FROM #Sample S
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(S.S) >= T.N
GROUP BY S.S;
```

For future reference, also post your owns attempts please. We aren't here (really) to do your work for you.

Comment: `select IsNumeric( '.' );`?

Comment: Haha @HABO ... `SELECT isnumeric($), isnumeric(','), isnumeric('1,1,1')`

Comment: Yep, forgot about that stupidity of `ISNUMERIC`... Thanks to a `LIKE`

Comment: `LIKE '[0-9]' = 1`? The `= 1` appears to be spurious. (Aside: `IsNumeric()` returns `1` for 97 Unicode characters. Sigh.)

Comment: What I get for editting in the window and not pasting back into SSMS.

Comment: I just caught this: "Tally Table created by an rCTE"... Tally table, YES (DigitsOnlyEE, referenced above uses a tally tsbl)... Tally Table created by an rCTE, NO. The tally table is an alternative to the rCTE, using an rate is like hiring the best pilot in the world to fly you somewhere safely then getting them drunk. Note this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution with regular expressions (if you'd allow them):

it uses recursive CTE, at every recursive step, one digit is removed from given string and the condition is to stop, when there are no digits in string. The rows are also numbered with consecutive `id`s, so the last `id` is the amount of removed digits from string.

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'kick0my123ass';

with cte as (
    select 1 [id], stuff(@str,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str),1,'') [col]
    union all
    select [id] + 1, stuff([col],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [col]),1,'') from cte
    where col like '%[0-9]%'
)
--this will give you number of digits in string
select top 1 id from cte order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHILE` loop to each each character is a numeric or not.

**Query**

```
declare @text as varchar(max) = 'kick0my234ass';
declare @len as int;
select @len = len(@text);
if(@len > 0)
begin
    declare @i as int = 1;
    declare @count as int = 0;
    while(@i <= @len)
    begin
        if(substring(@text, @i, 1) like '[0-9]')
             set @count += 1;
        set @i += 1;
    end
    print 'Count of Numerics in ' + @text + ' : ' + cast(@count as varchar(100));
end
else
    print 'Empty string';
```

Answer (score 0):

If simplicity & performance are important I suggest a purely set-based solution. Grab a copy of [DigitsOnlyEE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/) which will remove all non-numeric characters. Then use LEN against the output.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = '123xxx45ff678';

SELECT string = @string, digitsOnly, DigitCount = LEN(digitsOnly)
FROM dbo.DigitsOnlyEE(@string);
```

**Results**

```
string             digitsOnly  DigitCount
------------------ ----------- ------------
123xxx45ff678      12345678    8
```